# Set probability range for heading in Netlogo

Tags: range, probability, netlogo, heading

My problem consists of 2 things:

1. how to code 4 different range for heading

   - a. 315 - 45
   - b. 46 - 135
   - c. 136 - 225
   - d. 226- 314

2.how to code probability on choosing this range.
(I have attached image below to make it clear)

What I wish to do is:

a) for heading a; the probability of turtles choose any of this range should be 85%

b) for heading b,c, and b, there will be 5% of turtles choosing any side of this heading

Since I'm quite bad at explaining in words, I have attached image on what I plan to do

[image: Right-click and open in new tab]

here is my code

```
to random-behave

  let p random-float 100

  if (p >= 85)
  [set  heading heading + 45
    set heading heading - 45]

  if (p >= 15)
   [set  heading other heading + 45
    set heading other heading - 45]

    if not can-move? 1 [ rt 180 ]

   fd 1
  ]
end
```

I tried to implement `rnd extension` but I can't see where should I put it. And if possible, instead of `if (p >=15)`, is there any way to code the heading according to its degree? Since `other` can't be use here.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need the `rnd` extension, your approach with `random-float` is fine. However, you need to use `if-else` rather than `if` because a returned random number 'p' that is >85 will also be >15. Instead, you need to break up the interval from 0 to 100 into pieces that are the appropriate length. This is not tested.

```
to random-behave

  let p random-float 100

  if-else p <= 85
  [ print "got up to 85" ]
  [ if-else p <= 90
    [ print "got 85 to 90"]
    [ if-else p <= 95
      [ print "got 90 to 95" ]
      [ print "got 95 to 100" ]
    ]
  ]

  if not can-move? 1 [ rt 180 ]
  fd 1
end
```

You also have errors in your `heading` calculation. I only answered the probability part since that's what you specifically asked. But you should ask a new question if you need help with your `heading`.

Comment: Thank youu so mucchh for helping me. This code works with what I plan to do. I will create new question regarding heading.